# Google Chrome: Footer links turn white after page reload on hover

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

When I scroll down to the footer in Google Chrome, reload the page and hover the links within the footer they turn white. I have this issue on multiple of my websites, but only in Google Chrome. I saw this problem also on bootstrap's website, you can try it here by yourself https://getbootstrap.com/
Excluding bootstrap css and js from my site didn't solve the problem.

As soon as I scroll the white background disappears, a quick solution was to scroll 0.1px with javascript, but this can't be a permanent solution.

Also worth mentioning is that the half of my footer turns white when my scroll to top button has finished fading in.

Any ideas what the origin of the problem is or possible solutions?

[image]

Comment: I am unable to replicate, do you have any extensions installed that may cause issues ?

Comment: also unable to replicate. what version of chrome and what platform are you using?

Comment: Ahh I didn't thought of this! Turned out a Google Calendar extension caused the issue. Thanks for the tip to check my extensions @CraigBezuidenhout

Comment: It was very strange, because I didnt have that issue on every site

Comment: No worries, extensions can be a pain :)

Answer (score 0):

Issue was caused by the Google Calendar extension.